# traversal.asAdmin().addStep(step) for remote calls

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, janusgraph, gremlin-server

I am trying to build complex traversals using Java client to a remote JanusGraph server.

The following traversal returns the ReferenceVertex elements identified by the label "mylabel":

```
GraphTraversal<Vertex, Vertex> t = g.V().hasLabel("mylabel");
List<Vertex> r = t.toList();
```

For more complex queries I need to concatenate multiple traversals that form a part of the whole queries. The following code illustrates the concept:

```
GraphTraversal<Vertex, Vertex> addMe = __.hasLabel("mylabel");
GraphTraversal<Vertex, Vertex> t = g.V();
for (Step<?, ?> step : addMe.asAdmin().getSteps()) {
     t.asAdmin().addStep(step);
}
List<Vertex> r = t.toList();
```

For local access this works. For remote access however, it returns all vertices available on the server, not the ones identified by the label.

In both cases, t.toString() returns

```
[GraphStep(vertex,[]), HasStep([~label.eq(mylabel)])]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to get into any of the `asAdmin()` methods. Rather than build anonymous traversals to try to append to a parent traversal, I think it would be better to just pass around the parent `GraphTraversal` instance and simply add steps to that as needed:

```
private static GraphTraversal addFilters(GraphTraversal t) {
    return t.hasLabel("mylabel");
}

...

GraphTraversal<Vertex, Vertex> t = g.V();
t = addFilters(t);
List<Vertex> r = t.toList();
```

There is a reason why your approach doesn't work with remote traversals and it has to do with how Gremlin bytecode is constructed behind the scenes. Using the `asAdmin()` methods bypasses some inner workings and those portions of the traversal are not sent to the server - that's a simple way of explaining it anyway. If you absolutely must construct anonymous portions of a traversal that way and then append them in that exact fashion then I guess I would do:

```
GraphTraversal<Vertex, Vertex> addMe = __.hasLabel("mylabel");
GraphTraversal<Vertex, Vertex> t = g.V();
List<Vertex> r = t.filter(addMe).toList();
```

I don't particularly like that approach because depending on what you're doing you could trick out JanusGraph traversal strategies that optimize your traversals and you'll lose some performance optimizations. I also don't like the style as much - it just seems more natural to pass around the `GraphTraversal` to the functions that need to mutate it with new steps. You might also find [this information](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/#traversal-component-reuse) about traversal re-use helpful.

Comment: nice to hear...could you please accept the answers since all is good?

Comment: Finally understand the problem in my case. In my case, all remote cases failured.